# Python regex : Replacing dots and signs followed by spaces

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace dot / ? / ! followed by spaced (if any) to a breakline char `\n`  and eliminate the whitespaces.
So in case of : `hello world. It's nice.` I want it to be `hello world.\nIt'snice.\n`
This is what I thought of (but it doesn't work, otherwise I wouldn't write this question ha? )

```
re.sub(r'\.!?( *)', r'.\n\1', line)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Why is one space in the example string removed and the other isn't? Did you mean `helloworld.\nIt'snice.\n` or `hello world.\nIt's nice.\n`?

Comment: It is not following any dot or other characters I want to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match spaces or the end of the string with a positive look-behind:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[.?!])( +|\Z)', r'\n', text)
```

Because this matches just spaces that are preceded by punctuation, you don't need to use a back reference.

The `+` ensures that only punctuation followed by a space is matched here. The text:

```
"His thoughts trailed away... His heart wasn't in it!"
```

would otherwise receive too many newlines.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "hello world. It's nice."
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[.?!])( +|\Z)', r'\n', text)
"hello world.\nIt's nice.\n"
>>> text = "His thoughts trailed away... His heart wasn't in it!"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[.?!])( +|$)', r'\n', text)
"His thoughts trailed away...\nHis heart wasn't in it!\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

Without lookaround:

```
>>> import re
>>> line="hello world! What? It's nice."
>>> re.sub(r'([.?!]+) *', r'\1\n', line)   # Capture punctuations; discard spaces
"hello world!\nWhat?\nIt's nice.\n"

>>> line="hello world! His thoughts trailed away... What?"
>>> re.sub(r'([.?!]+) *', r'\1\n', line)
'hello world!\nHis thoughts trailed away...\nWhat?\n'
```

Comment: This'll also match `"His thoughts trailed away..."` and insert newlines after every dot. Then again, so will mine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The point that you mentioned should be handled in the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `replace`?

```
print text.replace('. ','.\n').replace('? ','?\n').replace('! ','!\n')
```

Comment: But in case there is more than one space it will not be replaced. Just the first one will.